# Cimg compilation error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cimg

i get this error when i add CIMG library to Xcode:

'cstdio' file not found

this is the library link:
http://cimg.sourceforge.net/

help please

Comment: how to use cimg library in iPhone ? how to add this library to Xcode?

Comment: Consider using CoreGraphics to deal with images.

Comment: CoreGraphics not suitable for Image filtering , like cartoon effect

Comment: CoreImage probably is, though, and it is available from iOS 5.0.

Comment: If he really wanted to, he could use GL for this.

Comment: i want to filter the image to get the this output :

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bxjx-OJ_OAWDa1drTS1iMmJyeWs


https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bxjx-OJ_OAWDeHZ4eE1zWFc0Y1k


https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bxjx-OJ_OAWDeHZ4eE1zWFc0Y1k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GPUImageFramework it is an awesome one for image processing

Answer (score 0):

Your source file extension needs to be the type that accepts C++ (.cpp), or ObjC++ (.mm) before you can even begin to think about using C++ libs.  Of course, CImg is not made to be run on iOS devices (especially if you can't see it's source).  It's not even officially supposed to run on OS X (because of Carbon support issues).  Use OpenGL, CoreImage, CoreGraphics, etc. for much better performance and support.

Comment: `cstdio` is a valid C++ header. `stdio` is neither valid in C (where it should be `stdio.h`) nor in C++ (where it should be, indeed, `cstdio`).

Comment: I'm not in front of my Mac so I can't verify my claim, but `cstdio` is part of the standard C++ library, so I would think Xcode ships with it. I recall using it in a few projects and I don't think I've ever installed an alternative standard C++ library. Even if there is indeed no `cstdio`, suggesting `stdio` alone definitely won't solve the problem.

Comment: Please try with `#include <cstdio>`, and not `#include <cstdio.h>`. It shouldn't have the .h extension. Also make sure the file has a C++ extension (`.cc` or `.cpp`) and that you're using `clang++` instead of just `clang`.

Comment: i removed the c from cstdio, and use stdio.h instead, but i get this error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

Comment: My only grief about your answer is that the C header is called `stdio.h`, not just `stdio`; whereas in C++ it's just `cstdio`, and not `cstdio.h`.

Comment: @zneak, the header change helped.  It's a matter of file extensions.  Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: the cimg library contain .h files , no .cpp files